# MATLAB edge function

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, threshold

I have a question regarding the parameters in the *edge* function.

```
 edge(img,'sobel',threshold);
 edge(img,'prewitt',threshold) ;
 edge(img,'roberts',threshold);
 edge(img,'canny',thresh_canny,sigma);
```

How should the threshold for the first 3 types be chosen? Is there an aspect that can help choosing this threshold (like histogram for instance)? I am aware of the function *graythresh* but I want to set it manually. So far I know it's a value between 0-1, but I don't know how to interpret it.

Same thing for Canny. I`m trying to input an array for thresh_canny = [low_limit, high_limit]. but don't know how to look at these values. How does the sigma value influence the image?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of edge you want to see in the output. If you want to see really powerful edges, use a smaller interval in the higher end of `threshold` (say 0.9-1) and this is relative to highest gradient magnitude of the image.

As far as the `sigma` is concerned, it is used in filtering the input image before passing to `edge`. This is to reduce noise in the input image.